# ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am getting this error while trying to run a rails app.

> ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable in Pages#home

I installed `rubyracer` but didn't help me.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>    true %>
```

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing `Node.js`:

```
brew install node # For Mac OSX
sudo apt-get install nodejs # For Ubuntu
```

See [other ways of installing Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) in your system.

Then, re-start your server. This should fix your issue.